# DataBinding Issue with BR file

Tags: android, data-binding, viewmodel, android-databinding

I am using `<include>` to include some layouts within parent layout.

**Problem:**
Some of my viewModel fields are generated in BR file and some are missing. What is the problem?

**Description:**

- Missing fields are used in layout which is included with `<include>` tag.
- Generated fields are used in parent layout.

For example:

In below code BR.name variable name is generated in BR file and used in parent layout.

```
public void setName(String phoneNumber){
       this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
       notifyPropertyChanged(BR.phoneNumber);
    }
```

And in below code password is missing in BR file which is used in child layout.

```
public void setPassword(String password){
   this.password = password;
   notifyPropertyChanged(BR.password);
}
```

Any help about why this is happening?

**What I've tried so far?**

I restarted android studio and invalidated its cache but still facing issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hurrah! I found solution [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) at google's official site.

"The Bindable annotation generates an entry in the BR class file during compilation. "

So I just have to add @Bindable annotation on getters.